# Failed to load plugin 'jest' declared in 'package.json » eslint-config-react-app/jest': Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I just started working on my react app in the morning, as I am new to react I was understanding it step by step. Till now I only used two images as logos and some buttons and css related to them in App.js and App.css file. Other than these two I haven't touched any file. It was working all fine but after some time at night I'm getting this error I don't know why. When I save App.css file it works fine without error but when I save App.js file it throws this error. Please help me to solve this error!!!!!.

[image: When I save App.js file I get this error on chrome as well as on terminal]
[image: But when I save App.css file it works fine.]

Comment: Please add code as code blocks not screenshots